# Question about none negative reputation system

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, voting, down-votes

## Story

A question got down-voted to hell, scored like -7 or -8, and I was the first one who cast a down vote.

---

At first, the OP got **3** reputation when posted the question:

> OP  reputation:  **3**
>
> Question Score: 0

The reputation reduced to **1** after I down voted it:

> OP  reputation:  **1**
>
> Question Score: -1

After a couple minutes, the question got down voted to hell:

> OP  reputation:  **1** (locked at 1 rept.)
>
> Question Score: -8

A nice guy jumped in and edited the post to make it a better question, so I decided to withdraw my down vote, and the situation became:

> OP  reputation:  **3**
>
> Question Score: -7 (mine has been withdrawn)

---

## Question

Why OP's reputation restored to **3** ? It seems my withdrawing **nullified** the reputation decrease from all the other down votes. Is this a bug? After all, it seems

> OP reputation: **1**
>
> Question Score: -7 (mine has been withdrawn)

is more reasonable after my withdrawing.

Comment: Marking as declined because there isn't really anything to do here; even if wrong, it will become right automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rep recalc (it's automatic) will solve this problem - system can't understand it *immediatly* that now the *second* downvote should cost 2 reps to OP.

Also, the fact that you retracted your vote didn't nullify rep loss from other downvotes - it was 0 already.